# same linq query generate different sql in different projects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Query is:

```
        var query =
                from stokHareket1 in ce.StokHarekets
                from stokHareket2 in ce.StokHarekets
                join stok in ce.Stoks on stokHareket1.StokId equals stok.Id
                where (
                stokHareket1.StokId == stokHareket2.StokId
                )
                select new
                {
                    result = stokHareket1.StokId
                };
```

In first project EF version is: **5.0.0** and in the second one: **6.1.3**

it gives in first project:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StokId] AS [StokId]
FROM  [dbo].[StokHareket] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StokHareket] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[StokId] = [Extent2].[StokId]
WHERE [Extent1].[StokId] IS NOT NULL
```

in second one:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StokId] AS [StokId]
FROM  [dbo].[StokHareket] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StokHareket] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[StokId] = [Extent2].[StokId])   
/*THIS LINE*/OR (([Extent1].[StokId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[StokId] IS NULL)) 
WHERE [Extent1].[StokId] IS NOT NULL
```

`/*THIS LINE*/` is different

What could be reason for this difference?

To better visualize, here is screen shots :

In db, stokHareket Table

[image]

In Edmx:

[image]

Comment: Is `StokId` nullable in one of the projects?  Is the version of EF that you're referencing the same?

Comment: In db allows null is checked but in edmx  nullable (None)

Comment: Has that changed at some point?  You could try manually setting the nullable property to `True` in the EDMX.  In either case it sohuldn;t change your results since the `WHERE` clause will exclude any null IDs.

Comment: In first project EF version is: `5.0.0` and in the second one: `6.1.3`

Comment: `setting the nullable property to True in the EDMX` did not change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a change introduced in EF6 (possibly earlier; I haven't found conclusive evidence).  EF6 started injecting .NET null comparison rules (`null == null` is true) into SQL queries, unless you set the `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` property on the context's configuration to `true`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
    }
}
```

In any case, it won't affect your results - the `WHERE` clause is filtering out any records where `StokId` is null.

Comment: It affects result, I don't want to include result `stokId` being null. Your suggestion gives the same result as it is in previous EF version. Thanks